# ReduceRight without reversing the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I've written reduce native implementation for JavaScript. But I'm looking to see if we can implement ReduceRight using this reduce.

```
Array.prototype.myReduce = function(cb, initialVal) {
  if (!cb)
    throw new Error("No CB defined");

  let [accumulator, ...arr] = initialVal === undefined ? [...this] : [initialVal, ...this];

  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    accumulator = cb.call(undefined, accumulator, arr[i], i, arr);
  }

  return accumulator;
}
```

I read from [this article](https://blog.jeremyfairbank.com/javascript/functional-javascript-lists-1/) that

> Now you might notice something. Is not map just a special case of
>   reduce? Yes! In fact we can implement map in terms of reduce's cousin
>   reduceRight. reduceRight is just like reduce except it reduces the
>   list items in the reverse direction. So, it would first encounter Nil,
>   then the next-to-last item, and keep going until it reaches the first
>   item in the list. reduceRight can be implemented as follows:

I'm not able to understand how I can implement reduceRight (**WITHOUT** reversing the array)

This is my implementation:

```
Array.prototype.myReduceRight2 = function(cb, initialVal) {
  if (!cb)
    throw new Error("No CB defined");

  const arr = [...this].reverse(); //DONOT REVERSE! Looking for alternate solution(s)

  const res = arr.myReduce((acc, val) => {
    return acc.concat(val);
  }, initialVal); // pass initialVal

  return res;
}
```

Comment: It appears you forgot to include a link to the article.

Comment: Oops. Thank you. Added

Comment: If `reduceRight` hadn't been reducing the list items in the reverse direction it would be `reduce`. Not sure what is asked here...

Comment: I'm also very confused.  Why do you want to `reduceRight` and why is `reduce` not acceptable?

Comment: Sorry if i'm not being clear. I want to use Reduce inside reduce right but instead of reversing an array (my solution attached), i wanted to see if there's any other solution. (in my case, i need to travel array twice)

Comment: "'m not able to understand how I can implement reduceRight (WITHOUT reversing the array)" - decrement the iteration in the loop, rather than increment it. Also, why don't you use the native reduceRight and/or polyfill?

Answer (score 3):

The following is the implementation of `reduceRight` I use in my personal library.

**Code:**

```js
Array.prototype.myReduceRight = function(callback, initialValue) {
  var
    /* Cache the length of the context. */
    length = this.length >>> 0,

    /* Create a counter defaulting at the index of the last element in the context. */
    counter = length - 1;

  /* Check whether a second argument has been given or not. */
  if (arguments.length < 2) {
    /* Repeat until the counter is less than or equal to the length of the
       context or when the counter exists as an index in the context. */
    while (counter >= 0 && !(counter in this)) {
      /* Decrement the counter. */
      counter--;
    }

    /* Set the inital value. */
    initialValue = this[counter--];
  }

  /* Repeat until the counter is less than 0. */
  while (counter >= 0) {
    /* Check whether the counter exists as an index in the context. */
    if (counter in this) {
      /* Set the initial value to be the return value of the given callback. */
      initialValue = callback.call(this, initialValue, this[counter], counter, this);
    }

    /* Decrement the counter. */
    counter--;
  }

  /* Return the calculated value. */
  return initialValue;
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(array.myReduceRight((acc, cur) => acc + cur));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you use Reduce for reduce right and not reverse the array?

Comment: @TechnoCorner not really, no, unless you just do two elements at a time from the original array.

Comment: @Angel Politis, would be really helpful if the code had some comments. Just trying to understand what's happening here.

Comment: See my edit @TechnoCorner. I hope it's better now 

Answer (score 2):

In functional programming, `reduce` aka `foldl` reduces like this

```
foldl (fn, [head:tail], acc) = foldl (fn, tail, fn(acc, head))
```

and `foldr` is this

```
foldr (fn, [head:tail], acc) = fn (head, foldr(fn, tail, acc))
```

while JS `reduceRight` has its arguments reversed:

```
reduceRight (fn, [head:tail], acc) = fn (reduceRight(fn, tail, acc), head)
```

All three in javascript:

```js
let nil = x => x === nil;

let reduce      = (fn, [h=nil, ...t], a) => nil(h) ? a : reduce(fn, t, fn(a, h));
let foldr       = (fn, [h=nil, ...t], a) => nil(h) ? a : fn(h, foldr(fn, t, a));
let reduceRight = (fn, [h=nil, ...t], a) => nil(h) ? a : fn(reduceRight(fn, t, a), h);

////

xs = [1,2,3,4]
list = (a, b) => `(${a} + ${b})`;

console.log(reduce(list, xs, ''));
console.log(foldr(list, xs, ''));
console.log(reduceRight(list, xs, ''));
```

To express `map` in terms of `foldr`, you'll need something like this:

```
let cons = (h, t) => [h, ...t];
let map = (fn, xs) => foldr((x, a) => cons(fn(x), a), xs, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight#Polyfill) is a reduceRight polyfill:

It uses a loop which decrements rather than increments as in your solution.

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.22
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.22
if ('function' !== typeof Array.prototype.reduceRight) {
  Array.prototype.reduceRight = function(callback /*, initialValue*/) {
    'use strict';
    if (null === this || 'undefined' === typeof this) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.reduce called on null or undefined');
    }
    if ('function' !== typeof callback) {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }
    var t = Object(this), len = t.length >>> 0, k = len - 1, value;
    if (arguments.length >= 2) {
      value = arguments[1];
    } else {
      while (k >= 0 && !(k in t)) {
        k--;
      }
      if (k < 0) {
        throw new TypeError('Reduce of empty array with no initial value');
      }
      value = t[k--];
    }
    for (; k >= 0; k--) {
      if (k in t) {
        value = callback(value, t[k], k, t);
      }
    }
    return value;
  };
}
```